# USB ports stopped working

Tags: 14.04, usb

All USB ports on my computer stopped working after my last restart. They do work at the BIOS stage and when I boot from a Live CD. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you include the output from `lsusb`?

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to transfer the output since the USB ports are not working and so I can't even connect my wireless card, but it looks like the USB ports are recognized. I can even see the Microsoft mouse connected to one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to kernel version 4.2.0-35-generic helped.